# Cannot recognize database

Tags: database

I got a part of sources of code and database file with "db4" extension. And I can't figure out what is the database. I know that database is SQL database and provides its API via ODBC.
Here the link to database file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-TkB6wRP9C9kNkK4jNEp546QZE75qwoq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: My google says  [dBase IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBase)

Answer (score 0):

As Joakim Danielson mentioned, This is dBase4 file.

If you are interested in exploring the file further more, why don't you download dBASE PLUS Trial Evaluation and let us know what you get..

Could you share what language you are using? Java or .NET 
Thank you !

Comment: I thought dBASE uses 'dbf' as file extensions. I'll try to use dBASE Plus.Thank you